# Access devise helpers from a mailer *preview*?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This *attempts* to render the correct view (I think):

```
class DeviseMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end
end
```

However, it chokes on the `confirmation_url` helper that's actually used in the view (no method error). Adding `include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers` doesn't resolve the error (or change anything else I can identify), and trying to do things like `helper :all`, `helper ApplicationHelper`, etc, gets an `undefined method helper` error.

Any ideas? There appears to be something Very Different going on between the mailer *base*, and the mailer *preview*.